# `brew doctor` gives warning for newly opened terminal windows

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew doctor` I get this warning:

`Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin`

TONS of people with the same problem, but they solve it by running this:

`PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Which fixes it once, but upon closing the terminal windows and opening a new one and running `brew doctor`, the warning re-appears.

Is there a permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `PATH` variable in your `~/.profile` (assuming you have not changed your default login shell).
There should be something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

change it so that `/usr/local/bin` in before `/usr/bin`.

If you do not have a `~/.profile` (or it is empty) type the following:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH' >> ~/.profile,
```

Make certain that you use `>>` instead of one `>`.

Now edit the `~/.profile` like described before.

Comment: My .profile file is empty upon entering `sudo nano ~/.profile`

Comment: added more information @JacksonGariety

Comment: Thanks! So my .profile now looks like this and it's saved:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin`

But it gives me the same error. Is a restart needed here?

Comment: close and reopen the Teminal

Comment: That didn't do the trick. It seems brew isn't using the correct path? EDIT: Yeah, if I `echo $PATH` in terminal it shows me a really weird set of paths many which point to `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin` It definitely is not using the `$PATH` from my .profile

Comment: Shouldn't that file be called `.bash_profile` instead of just `.profile`?

Comment: It could be in either `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.bashrc` already.

Comment: My `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.bashrc` all have some weird jargon referring to `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. The ~/.profile is the file I made and that has the correct PATH settings. Should I copy that into the other 3 files? What PATH is it using? Where is that stored!?

Comment: Added my path to every single file and `brew doctor` still tells me to change my path. This is infuriating.